# Duplicate inbox message about answers to a bountied question that is also being followed

Tags: bug, bounties, notifications, follow-post

I received two notifications in my inbox about the same answer being posted.

[image: Double notification for answer]

As you can see, one is due to the fact I followed the question a couple of days ago. The other I recognize as being due to the bounty I placed on the question recently. This appears to be a bug.

To contrast, comments left on the post since the bounty (also pictured) are not getting duplicated.

Comment: Comments are not duplicated because we don't get notifications for comments on questions where we started a bounty, just for answers. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask - I vaguely recall getting notified on comments to bountied question previously. Though admittedly, the previous bounty I posted was quite a long time go, so have to account for faulty memory and all that.

Comment: Most likely you had the bounty on your own question, so you get comment notifications for that anyway.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask - Nope. I have yet to post a bounty on one of my own.

Comment: If you mean notification for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452953/print-macro-values-without-knowing-the-amount-of-macros#comment81860748_47452953) (which doesn't have direct ping) it's because you're the only user commenting, except the OP - it's by design and not related to bounty. If you remember what comment you got notified about which you shouldn't have, link to it and I'll take a look.

Comment: This just happened to me after starting a bounty on someone else's question that I was already following.